# Xubuntu 22.04 freezes on login screen

Tags: boot, xubuntu, login-screen

I'm running Xubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Thinkcentre M710s SFF (no Nvidia) that I bought used. There have been occasional problems with it turning on, but it has mostly worked.

Today, the machine booted to the login screen and then froze. No keyboard, no mouse, though the cursor blinked for a bit before stopping.

I can't TTY since the there is no keyboard or mouse. I booted from recovery mode, so the keyboard works until there is a screen. But then the same thing happened when I got to the recovery menu -- no keyboard or mouse (and there is only one kernel listed on grub). I tried booting from a USB, and the same thing happened when I got to the USB home screen -- no keyboard or mouse.

And I can't send any logs because everything is frozen.

I have also tried a hard boot/reset, but the machine powers on when plugging the cord back in. So I'm wondering if this is a hardware problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.